# MYSQL Query to check if Value is Null/Blank

Tags: mysql

My Query looks like this

```
SELECT Distinct tm.teamid,tm.Team_Name,CONCAT_WS(' ',tu.FirstName+' '+tu.LastName) as Leader  FROM tblGameRelation tgr 
LEFT JOIN tblTeam tm ON tgr.teamid = tm.teamid AND tgr.gameid = 62
LEFT JOIN tblUsersRelation tur ON tgr.typeid=tur.typeid AND tur.usertypeid=1
LEFT JOIN tblUsers tu ON tu.UserId= tur.UserId
```

My Problem is that when "Leader" field is Blank it should display "-" a Dash.I tried using if null but its not working, not sure if Mysql can do this, i know its possible in MSSQL SERVER

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is your friend here:

```
COALESCE(CONCAT_WS(' ', tu.FirstName, tu.LastName), '-') AS leader
```

`COALESCE()` will pick the first expression, value or field given to it that isn't NULL and returns it.

Comment: +1. Change the concatenation from `CONCAT_WS(' ',tu.FirstName+' '+tu.LastName)` to `CONCAT_WS(' ', tu.FirstName, tu.LastName)`.